# MySQL PHPExcel query taking too long to execute

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel, zend-server

I am running a PHPExcel output from MySQL.

When I run the code and output to Excel with a few lines of the output everything is fine, when I run the following code I am getting nowhere apart from a very long query execution time according to the zend server logs.

I am not getting an output at all, I get a request to open a PHP file after what seems an eternity!

Any assistance appreciated.

here's the code so far:

```
$queryGetIMEI = "SELECT DISTINCT(wi_iridium_og_device) FROM wi_iridium_og ORDER BY wi_iridium_og_device DESC";
//declare the new array for the IMEI numbers
$IMEI = array();

if ($result = $mysqli->query($queryGetIMEI)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $IMEI[] = $row["wi_iridium_og_device"];
    }
    /* free result set */
    $result->free();
}

// call the PHPexcel Files
require_once 'classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once 'classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';


$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$sheet_count = 0;


foreach ($IMEI as $c) {
    if ($sheet_count > 0) {

        // This creates the next sheet in the sequence
        // One sheet per IMEI in this example
        $objPHPExcel->createSheet();
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($sheet_count);
    }

    // Add tab label to the sheet
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle(substr($c,0,30));

    // Column headings in the first row
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1','Device');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B1','Site Reference');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C1','Charge Type');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D1','Date');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E1','Time');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F1','Number Called');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G1','Service');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H1','Call Termination');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I1','MSISDN');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J1','Originating Country');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K1','UNUSED_3');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L1','UNUSED_4');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('M1','UNUSED_5');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('N1','UNUSED_6');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('O1','UNUSED_7');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('P1','UNUSED_8');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('Q1','Units');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('R1','Currency');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('S1','Charge');

    // Dynamic data comes next
    // Query the DB based on the IMEI value. Pass the result to the while loop

    $query_GetBillPerIMEI = "SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE wi_iridium_og_device, wi_iridium_og_charge_type, wi_iridium_og_date, wi_iridium_og_time, wi_iridium_og_number_called, wi_iridium_og_service FROM wi_iridium_og WHERE wi_iridium_og_device = ". $c ." AND  wi_iridium_og.wi_iridium_og_charge_type != 'SBD Overage' ORDER BY wi_iridium_og_charge_type ASC";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query_GetBillPerIMEI);    
    $rowcount = 2;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()){

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A' .$rowcount, $row['wi_iridium_og_device']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B' .$rowcount, $row['wi_iridium_og_site_reference']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C' .$rowcount, $row['wi_iridium_og_charge_type']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D' .$rowcount, $row['wi_iridium_og_date']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E' .$rowcount, $row['wi_iridium_og_time']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F' .$rowcount, $row['wi_iridium_og_number_called']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('G' .$rowcount, $row['wi_iridium_og_service']);
```

When I add the following line to the output:

```
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('G' .$rowcount, $row['wi_iridium_og_service']);
```

The file then fails to run and produce the output.

I have over 30,000 entries in the database that need to be queried.

Help!!!

Comment: It doesn't help that you're nesting your queries: can't you use a JOIN so that you're only doing a single query?

Comment: Use techniques such as fromArray() to populate the PHPExcel data rather than populate every individual cell, or at least use the fluent interface so you're not calling getActiveSheet() for every single cell

Comment: And you're wasting resources like memory: you're iterating a database cursor `$result` and loading every record in memory. Why you're not dealing with data at the same time that you have access to it?

Comment: @PauloASilva, fully understand that it's a memory issue causing the error. How would I best rework the shown code to not load all in the memory?

Comment: First of all try to avoid going to database for each IMEI (suggested by @Mark Baker) then first prepare the Spreadsheet and then build it while iterating the database resultset

Comment: ah, and I did fail making you aware that this query `"SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE wi_iridium_og_device, wi_iridium_og_charge_type, wi_iridium_og_date, wi_iridium_og_time, wi_iridium_og_number_called, wi_iridium_og_service FROM wi_iridium_og WHERE wi_iridium_og_device = ". $c ." AND  wi_iridium_og.wi_iridium_og_charge_type != 'SBD Overage' ORDER BY wi_iridium_og_charge_type ASC";` is vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: @PauloASilva, thanks I will try to rework the code so we aren't iterating repeatedly. I'm a bit of a novice at this, probably the hardest thing I've done so a total n00b!! :)

Comment: @MarkBaker, thanks, I will look at the fromArray function and try to improve my code.

Comment: @PauloASilva, Re SQL Injection. How would I protect against that by improving the query? If so, can you give an example of better code?

Answer (score 0):

First of all read about [PHP PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php): this will be enough to deal with/avoid SQL injection (the problem on your query is in here `WHERE wi_iridium_og_device = ". $c ." AND` because you don't know the value of `$c` which could be harmful).

About how to rework to improve your source code performance... (this won't be functional, read it as pseudo-code)

```
<?php
// call the PHPexcel Files
require_once 'classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once 'classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$sheet_count = 0;

$queryGetIMEI = "SELECT DISTINCT(wi_iridium_og_device) FROM wi_iridium_og ORDER BY wi_iridium_og_device DESC";

//declare the new array for the IMEI numbers

if ($result = $mysqli->query($queryGetIMEI))
{
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array())
    {
        // your foreach login in here (without the foreach)
    }
}
```

This should improve your memory footprint, but probably you're also able to improve your queries.